# Parsing POST request data with FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm tring to capture a local POST requset and parse its data.
For testing only, the FiddlerCore should only response with the data it has parsed.
Here's the code of the FidlerCore encapsulation:

```
private void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession)
{
    if (oSession.hostname != "localhost") return;

    eventLog.WriteEntry("Handling local request...");
    oSession.bBufferResponse = true;
    oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
    oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "200 Ok";
    oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    oSession.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";

    string body = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(body);
}
```

Here's the code of the request sender:

```
const string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";

try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/?action=print");
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = "text/html";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        txtResponse.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string responseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
                txtResponse.Text = responseFromServer;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    txtResponse.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> **The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would you know how to get the Request Payload in Fiddler.Session object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by changing:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/?action=print");
```

to

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8877/?action=print");
```

Calling this URL from a browser is intercepted by FiddlerCore correctly, without having to specify the port number. I did not think I should have inserted the listening port, since FiddlerCore should intercept all traffic, right?

Comment: Fiddler captures all requests where the client is set to use it as the proxy. .NET applications may or may not adopt the system's proxy setting (and you don't show whether you've even configured FiddlerCore to register as the system proxy). By specifying the port, you're effectively using FiddlerCore directly as a reverse-proxy.

Comment: I did register FiddlerCore as a system proxy like so - `FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);` but since it is hosted in a Windows Service, it is behaving differently. When starting the service, it does not set the browser's proxy settings like when it is hosted in a Windows Application. So when trying to call a local method, for the service to handle, I've notice I must include the port number, even when calling it from a browser like so - `http://localhost:8877/?Action=Print&PrinterID=Printer1`.

Comment: @EricLaw I think I understand what is going on - the service, which holds the FiddlerCore, is using LocalSystem account and register the FiddlerCore with this account as well, but the user is using its own account. How can I register FiddlerCore using the user account and not the service account?

Comment: Either run FiddlerCore in the user's account, or impersonate the user and set his/her proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888.

Comment: One solution I found is to use your very own SetProxy application. I ran it while setting up the service and let it setup the proxy settings. Can you provide a code sample of how to impersonate a user credentials?

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could provide the source code of the SetProxy application?